# How to set up D-Link router DIR-655

Tags: router

I have the router plugged in directly to my modem. The default wireless network "dlink" appears, but when I connect to it, it has no service. How can I set it up? (I have no CDs)

Thanks!

Comment: What does "it has no service" mean? You need to describe the actual problem in some level of detail. (Do you connect to the network? Do you get assigned an IP address? Can you reach the router?)

Comment: I just tried it and I can't even connect to it. The network "dlink" is unsecured. I want to be able to (a) connect to it, and (b) change the security settings on it. Is that possible?

Comment: What is the "it" you can't connect to? Do you mean you can't connect to the wireless network? (If so, what happens when you double-click on it?) Do you mean you can't connect to the router? If so, are you assigned an IP address? You need to describe the problem in some detail.

Comment: When I click on 'Connect' under the 'd-link' wireless network, nothing happens, and I have no internet. I cannot connect to the router.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", does that mean you connect to the network and nothing happens? Or does that mean you do not connect to the network? Do you get assigned an IP address? (Don't worry about whether you have Internet or not, that's 80 steps later. Be methodical and don't even think about Internet access until you've established that you can connect to the wireless network, are assigned an IP address, and can reach the router itself. Do one step at a time.)

Answer (score 1):

There should be a setup wizard in the router firmware which can be accessed using your browser, type in 192.168.0.1 into the browser address bar, then admin and leave the password blank and hit enter, this will allow you into the router configuration.

If someone set a password you will have to reset the router to defaults.

For more detailed information [Go to this page and type the model number](http://www.dlink.com/support/) in the product support box and hit enter.

Comment: My d-link router is currently plugged into my SMC Networks modem/router, so when I type in 192.168.0.1, it goes to the SMC Networks login instead =S i'm trying to add the d-link because the wireless signal is much better.

Comment: Disconnect the Dlink from the SMC, see if you can load the dlink page now.